# Adding a root node to XML after pulling from a file without a root node

Tags: xml, parsing

I have code which logs method calls. So that it is able to log by just appending at the end, I am having it log without a root node... so the structure is like this...

```
<method>
    <handle id="0"/>
    <timestamp>0</timestamp>
    <signature>int[] path.getSelectedObjectIds()</signature>
    <arguements>
        <argument>rO0ABXA=</argument>
    </arguements>
    <return>value</return>
</method>

<method>
    <handle id="0"/>
    <timestamp>0</timestamp>
    <signature>int path.getObjectIDFromKey(String)</signature>
    <arguements>
        <argument>Selectable1</argument>
        <argument>2</argument>
    </arguements>
    <return>value</return>
</method>
```

so now i'm trying to read this file for playback with something like this

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new File("methodLog.txt"));

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList listOfMethods = doc.getElementsByTagName("method");
        int totalMethods = listOfMethods.getLength();
        System.out.println("Number of methods: " + totalMethods);

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfMethods.getLength(); i++) {
           ...
```

and getting an error that the document must be well-formed. is there a quick way to throw a root tag (say "methods") around what currently exists in the file right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem by using htmltext into xml. It was

```
<p align="left"><font..>text</font></p><p align="left"><font ..>text</font></p>
```

I parsed it into string and just added the tags:

```
var s:String = xmlfile.toXmlString(); //don't know what it is in your language I use AS3
var newString:String = "<html>" + s + "</html>"; //adding the tags
xmlfile = new XML(newString); //parse new string into xml
```

So the output of the new xml was:

```
<html>
     <p align="left">
          <font..>text</font>
     </p>
     <p align="left">
          <font ..>text</font>
     </p>
</html>
```

It a simple way to make it work. Hope this could help you.